# How to have first function "foo1()" finished processing before running $.when() afterward??

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred, .when

I'm using JQuery v2.0.0

How do I make these functions run in top to bottom order instead of an asynchrous-like effect or order, meaning don't let the function "foo2()" run before the function "foo1()" is done first.

```
foo1();

$.when( foo2() )
    .done(function() { $('#test').dialog('close');  foo3(); })
    .fail(function() { alert('You have a problem!!');  foo3(); });
```

Thanks...

Comment: Use .done on foo1(), assuming foo1() returns a promise object. also, your $.when is not necessary, you can do foo2().done, also assuming foo2() returns a promise object. If neither return promise objects, then your code won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `foo1` looks something like this:

```
function foo1() {
    var promise = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({...}).done(function() { promise.resolve(); })
        .fail(function() { promise.reject(); });
    return promise;
}
```

You can do this:

```
foo1().done(function() {
    $.when( foo2() )
        .done(function() { $('#test').dialog('close');  foo3(); })
        .fail(function() { alert('You have a problem!!');  foo3(); });
});
```

...or as @Kevin B mentioned, like this:

```
foo1().done(function() {
    foo2()
        .done(function() { $('#test').dialog('close');  foo3(); })
        .fail(function() { alert('You have a problem!!');  foo3(); });
});
```

...but as comments point out, a better implementation of `foo1` would look like this, which you can do as long as `foo1` doesn't need to do any custom work during `done`, `fail`, or `always`.

```
function foo1() {
    return $.ajax({...});
}
```

Otherwise, if `foo1` is not async in any way, it will always complete first.

Comment: Two questions.   [1] Is foo1() suppose to return "promise.promise()" insetad of "promise"??   [2] foo1() have no $.ajax but I can implement $.Deferred() (or promise) but how would that works without AJAX?

Comment: @fletchsod "if foo1 is not async in any way, it will always complete first."

Comment: `function foo1() {
    return $.ajax()
}`  and `foo2().done(...)` to simplify code

Comment: To clarify what A. Wolff said: `$.ajax` is already a deferred, so there is no reason to wrap it in another deferred.

Comment: Also, the `promise` variable in `foo1`. is really a deferred and not a promise.  The difference between the two is deferreds can be canceled and promises cannot (think read-only).  You can create a read-only version by calling the `.promise()` method on a deferred.

Comment: Awesome!!  Many thanks to "A Wolff", "cereal77killer" and "Kevin B" for damn-good & piece-of-cake clarifications.  The JQuery Deferred is really confusing on many different JQuery versions.

Comment: Also, the accepted answer is using nested callbacks to control the sequence.  While this works, it is missing one of the major benefits of using deferreds: to AVOID callback hell.